# Automatic scrolling thumbnails for img gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to make a bunch of images i have automatically scroll on the page. I have looked around but can't quite seem to find a proper answer to do this. I don't think a carousel is what i'm looking for...the answer may lie with Jquery or JavaScript although I am unsure.

The layout:

[image: img gallery]

So, say I have 10 more images, how can I add them to this row to make them scroll by on screen?

the img gallery html:

```
<div style="background-color: #54c545;">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Grid row-->
    <div class="row py-4 d-flex align-items-center">

      <div class="container">
        <h2>Image Gallery</h2>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="thumbnail">

              <img src="img/holoContin.png" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">


            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end col -->
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="thumbnail">

              <img src="img/holoAns.png" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">


            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end col -->
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="thumbnail">

              <img src="img/holoAns.png" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">


            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end col -->
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="thumbnail">

              <img src="img/holoAns.png" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">


            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end col -->
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="thumbnail">

              <img src="img/holoAns.png" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">


            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end col -->
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="thumbnail">

              <img src="img/holoAns.png" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">


            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end col -->

        </div>
      </div>





    </div>
    <!-- Grid row-->

  </div>
  <!-- end img gallery container -->
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the code of the image gallery?!

Answer (score 1):

Why not Carousel: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/ ????

You can put your 10 more client images within `<a>` or directly under a `<div>` and initialize them with the plugin. In the fiddle example I used icons instead.

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/125272/

Since you didn't explain much in your OP, I didn't explain much on how to use the OwlCarousel plugin either. Please read their documentation.

Comment: that is what i was looking for, thanks. Just for some reason it shows all 10 at once in my containing div which makes it now scroll automatic like that. is there a way to limit whats visible?

Comment: @brooksyp: make sure you install OwlCarousel plugin correctly (refer back to its documentation) as you might need to include its javascript as well as its default css, and the theme css file. In my fiddle I already included them on the left menu. Also on the owlCarousel() configuration in the javascript section, you see `responsive` section. There I defined for 768px and up, I only display 5 items. So there is no way you see all 10 items at once, unless the plugin is not initialized correctly.

Comment: https://github.com/BrooksPatola/holocube-na/blob/master/index.html#L197

Comment: @ David Liang . if you take a look at line:191 that is where the gallery is supposed to begin. I have used a CDN in a script tag, and it seems to slide to the left, but everything was vertical when i tried what your snipped displayed. Can you take a look to see if I have something effecting this ?

Comment: @brooksyp: did you include the base style https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css and the theme style https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css? The theme style needs to be after the base style too.

Comment: @ David Liang . its now working. thanks for your time and help.